# In Rails, what is the difference using "has_many with belongs_to" vs "has_many with has_one"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to, has-one

For example, in

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :awards
end

class Awards < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end
```

the above should be the correct usage, but what if we use

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :awards
end

class Awards < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :student
end
```

doesn't the above also make possible `student.awards` as an array of Award objects, and `award.student` as a Student object which is the recipient of the award, so works the same way as the method at the top of post?

Comment: See: [Cardinality on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling%29)

Answer (score 8):

`has_one` is used in case of a one-to-one relationship, not in one-to-many relationships.

Correct use of `has_one`:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :id_card
end

class IdCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end
```

Comment: The point is: The class with the `belongs_to` statement is the class with the foreign key in its table schema.

Answer (score 3):

The two examples are not equivalent.

`has_many` and `belongs_to` work as a pair where there is a 'many to one' relationship.

In the database this would look like:

```
**Students**
Name
Email
...

**Awards**
Name
student_id  <-- !IMPORTANT!
...
```

Each `Student` has many awards hence `has_many :awards`
Each `Award` 'belongs to' a `Student` hence `belongs_to :student`

Notice that the `belongs_to` is applied to the table with the foreign key `student_id`.  This is important.

OK - so what happens where there is a 'one to one' relationship?

If each student could only have a single award then the database tables could  look exactly the same but the model should not be able to return a collection of items.

This is where we need the `has_one` declaration.  This would be applied to the `Student` model in this case.  Why?  Because the relationship is the same in both directions but Active Record needs to know where to find the foreign key.

If the database tables were the other way around with each `Student` having an `award_id` then the `Student` would get the `belongs_to` and the `Award` would get the `has_one`.

Hope that makes it clear?

It does seem a little odd to be that a student could 'belong to' an award if you use natural language.  But that is how the rails active record domain specific language is written.

It gets even more unnatural sounding when you look at the 'many to many' relationship with 'has_many_and_belongs_to'.  Here there is a joining table which site between your main tables like

```
students_awards
student_id
award_id
```

In this situation neither the `Students` nor the `Awards` table have a foreign key but both will carry the `has_many_and_belongs_to :other_table` declaration.  Both tables are able to join to multiple rows of the other.  Each `Student` can have more than one `Award`.  Each `Award` can be applied to many `Students`.

The `has_one` declaration is **only** used where there is a 'one-to-one' relationship and the table it applies to does **not** have the foreign key.